# Importing csv to Excel, CSV

Tags: vba, csv, import, excel-2007, overwrite

I have a excel 2007 workbook , with current worksheet named 'a' Now what I want is,

When user clicks a button in sheet a, it should ask,
Which csv file to import,
Ask for name of that new sheet user want (where that csv file is to be placed).. Say to simplify user says 'b' now.
After that copy 'sheet a' into the new sheet b.
Import the csv into that new sheet, comma delimted, and **allow overwriting of existing cells** in copied sheet.
What can be basic start level code to accomplish all these tasks?

I will be grateful for any help in this regard.

Thanks
Sal

Comment: Try recording a macro while doing that - use that as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    Public strFile As String

    Sub Main()

    Dim WS As Worksheet

        strFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel workbooks,*.csv*")
        If strFile = "False" Then
            ' the user clicked Cancel
        Else

        y = Right(strFile, Len(strFile) - InStrRev(strFile, "\", -1, vbTextCompare))

        zz = Left(y, InStr(1, y, ".", vbTextCompare) - 1)


        flag = 0
            For k = 1 To Worksheets.Count
                If Sheets(k).Name = zz Then
                    flag = 1
                End If
            Next
                 Set WS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count))
            If flag = 0 Then
                 WS.Name = zz
            Else
                MsgBox ("Sheet with same name already exist. Imported to default sheet")
            End If


            importcsv
        End If
    End Sub


    Sub importcsv()
        With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
            "TEXT;" & strFile, Destination:=Range( _
            "$A$1"))
            .FieldNames = True
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
            .TextFilePlatform = 437
            .TextFileStartRow = 1
            .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
            .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
            .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
            .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
            .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
            .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
            .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
            .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
            .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End Sub
```

Comment: & Is there a way that I rename my new worksheet with the name of the csv file selected by the user?  
Thanks  
Sal